# Text file is not getting created

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a file in the external SD card storage. The file is not getting created.
Interestingly, I have copied the create_file() from one of my otherprojects where it is working perfectly.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    create_file();
}


private void create_file() {
    String pathToExternalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .toString();
    File appDirectory = new File(pathToExternalStorage + "/" + "Accel");
    appDirectory.mkdirs();
    String fname = "Data.txt";
    File f_data = new File(appDirectory, fname);
    try {
        if (!f_data.exists()) {
            f_data.createNewFile();
            Toast.makeText(this, "File Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it throw an error? What happens when you run it? Nothing?

Comment: Is the toast presented?

Comment: I should avoid converting from File to String. You can do:

    `Final external = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File appDir = new File(external, "Accel");
    File fData = new File(appDir, "Data.txt);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I would check if proper permissions were added in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

What is more, I checked the docs and I guess instead of calling `.toString()`:

```
String pathToExternalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
```

you should rather use `.getPath()` method in there:

```
String pathToExternalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
```

Comment: I did not add the permission. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should add the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in your manifest.